# how to only log one line error message not several error message for my code

Tags: kotlin

there're several elements inside configTypeBuilderList, if the value in ruleAttributes not same as the destinationField in  ConfigTypeBuilder, it will log the error

```
ruleCriteriaList.forEach { configRuleCriteria ->

    validateConfigTypeBuilder(configRuleCriteria.configTypeBuilderList, ruleAttributesNames)
}

private fun validateConfigTypeBuilder(configTypeBuilderList: List<ConfigTypeBuilder>, ruleAttributes: List<String>) {
  val missAttributeList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

  configTypeBuilderList.forEach { configTypeBuilder ->
    if(configTypeBuilder!= null) {
    if (ruleAttributes.firstOrNull { ruleAttribute -> ruleAttribute == configTypeBuilder.destinationField } == null) {
      
      if(!ruleAttributes.contains(configTypeBuilder.destinationField)) {
           missAttributeList.add(configTypeBuilder.destinationField)
       }
       logger.error("{} is wrong", configTypeBuilder.destinationField)
     }
  } 

}
```

The problem is each time there's only one element(configTypeBuilderList) go into validateConfigTypeBuilder, so the logger shows like this

```
logger.error("field1 is wrong")
logger.error("field2 is wrong")
...
```

What I need is, how can I modify my code in order to do this?

```
logger.error("field1, field2, field3 are wrong")
```

*Edit*

I tried the first solution, but I stuck here, I still get the same error result, the reason is because each time there's only one "destinationField", how can I make the list have all the error field, and then log the error, can I use continue or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives:

1. Add them to a list and log later.

```
fun foo()
     val incorrectItems = mutableListOf<Any>()

     // Do some stuff
     
     // on error:
     incorrectItems.add(someIncorrectItem)

     // Do more stuff

     // log the accumulated errors:
     logger.error("${incorrectItems.joinToString("")} are wrong")
}
```

2. Partition your list into valid and invalid values. Log the invalid ones and process the good ones.

```
fun foo(someList: List<MyClass>) {
    val (goodItems, badItems) = someList.partition { it.isValid() } 
    // ...where isValid() is whatever code you need to check is OK.
    
    if (badItems.isNotEmpty()) {
        logger.error("${badItems.joinToString("")} are wrong")
    }

    // Do stuff with goodItems
}
```

Comment: Declare the list before the loop, not inside it.